# How can I get several oracle rows into one?

Tags: oracle

In this oracle situation, how can I get the following results in a single query?

```
Table 1
Customer | Order_Number  
1          1
1          2 
2          1 

Table 2 
Customer | Order_Number  | Employee | Tag
1            1             Bob        on hold
1            1             Larry      shipped
1            2             Larry      shipped

Results
Customer   | Order_Number   | Tags
1              1               Bob - on hold; Larry - shipped
1              2               Larry - shipped;
2              1               (Empty or null)
```

I'm getting tripped up on returning the tags as a single string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not mentioned your `DB version`. So the answer would completely depend on which version are you on.

If you are on `11g` and up, use `LISTAGG`.

However, if you are on `pre 11g` release, then you have the following options :

1. **ROW_NUMBER() and SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH functions in Oracle 9i**
2. **COLLECT function in Oracle 10g**
3. **STRAGG** function suggested by Tom Kyte here http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:2196162600402

Note : **Never** use `WM_CONCAT` in production system, it is undocumented. Just raise a SR to Oracle support and say you used it, and see the response. And it doesn't exist in `12c`.

More examples here http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/string-aggregation-techniques.php

Answer (score 1):

You're in need of [LISTAGG](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions100.htm#SQLRF30030).

If your Oracle version is old enough, it can be replaced with [user-defined aggregate function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28425/aggr_functions.htm), [WM_CONCAT](http://psoug.org/definition/wm_concat.htm) or [SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions164.htm).

Comment: **Never** use `WM_CONCAT` in production system, it is undocumented. Just raise a SR to Oracle support and say you used it, and see the response. And it doesn't exist in `12c`.